# Drag n Drop is NOT Happening

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Not sure what is the issue.. below code is supposed to work fine..

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class jusTrails {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\bala back up\\personel\\selenium\\Jars\\Drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get("http://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/drag-and-drop-demo.html");
        WebElement onlyOne=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Draggable 1')]"));

        System.out.println(onlyOne.getText());
        WebElement dropHere1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='mydropzone']"));
        Actions act=new Actions(driver);
        act.dragAndDrop(onlyOne, dropHere1).build().perform(); //This should work fine.. BUT.

    }

}
```

I am getting no exceptions but Draggable 1 wont move at all.. I tried this in another way but no luck..

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(onlyOne)
    .moveToElement(dropHere1)
    .release(dropHere1)
    .build();

dragAndDrop.perform();
```

Comment: check with your xpath

Comment: no xpath issues.. i am sure about that

Comment: in fact tried similar steps in http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/droppable/default.html i am able to do.. but not sure whats wrong with above one

Comment: It's probably [this issue](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/3604) which does not seem to be fixed even in 3.4.0 (tried with chrome and firefox).

Comment: woh okay thanks for the info @Morfic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is apparently a known [issue](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/3604) and there is a [workaround](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/3604#issuecomment-192002182). Granted it is in Ruby.

```
def drag_and_drop(source,target)

    js_filepath=File.dirname(__FILE__)+"/drag_and_drop_helper.js"
    js_file= File.new(js_filepath,"r")
    java_script=""

    while (line=js_file.gets)
      java_script+=line
    end

    js_file.close

    @driver.execute_script(java_script+"$('#{source}').simulateDragDrop({ 
dropTarget: '#{target}'});")

    rescue Exception => e
      puts "ERROR :" + e.to_s

  end
```

Comment: Its very unfortunate in java there is no workaround. thanks for the input @TitusLucretius