# Selenium/Java: Drag and drop operation not working for invisible elements

Tags: java, selenium, drag-and-drop

Using Selenium w/ Java bindings and ChromeDriver 2.3 with the latest browser installed

I'm currently stumped after more than enough time trying to find a solution.  I'm currently trying to drag and drop an element to another element.  The only catch is the element target I need to move to is only visible once I move the source element.  Any advice?

So here a screenshot of the source element that I click and hold, and then dragging it exposes the two options that I can drop too:

[Element that is the source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ud5GH.png)

So as I hold down the mouse and drag just a small portion, the drop targets become visible, per the screenshot below:

[Targets visible once mouse is dragged with source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/599ei.png)

Here is the latest code snippet I've tried that I believe should make this happen, but yet nothing happens and continues into the Thread.sleep(), which was only put in for observation purposes.  These are assuming healthy instances of WebDriverWait and WebDriver:

```
 driverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='user-info ng-binding'][text()='Sample Text']")));           
 driverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='user-info ng-binding'][text()='Sample Text']"))); 
 source = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='user-info ng-binding'][text()='Sample Text']"));

 //move to element, click and hold, and then move it to expose the available options
 actions.moveToElement(source).clickAndHold().pause(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).moveByOffset(10, 10).pause(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).build().perform();
 Thread.sleep(10000);
```

So the idea behind this is to just click and hold the source, move it a little to display the targets, and then find the targets, and use the actions.release() to move the target onto the source, but when I debug it it does nothing on the element to the element and goes straight to the Thread.sleep().  I've read about plenty of bugs.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/45037227/8020699 it looks like there is known issue with drag and drop in selenium

Comment: I have seen that thread.  I don't think my issue pertains to that as I cannot do a traditional drag and drop as the elements are not visible until the source is moved.

Comment: I am currently trying some of the combination of robot/selenium drag and drop workarounds from here:  https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/3604 I'll update if I do get any results

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I was looking for a solution but in the end I just made the hidden area visible. I know this isn't ideal but seems to work.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'display:block')", targetElement);
```

Comment: This would set an exception as the driver wouldn't be able to find the element?